# Telegram web app won't open on mobile devices

Tags: python, web-applications, bots, telegram

I'm writing a Telegram bot in Python that sends back from a **/start** command a button that when pressed, it should open a web app. Nothing so complicated so far. The problem that I'm having is that the web app ( a simple HTML file ) opens fine on the desktop version of Telegram ( Telegram web ) but it won't open on a mobile device. I tried more than one device. I must add that a demo Telegram web app ( Durger King ) runs fine in every mobile device and the desktop version.
The web app is just an HTML file hosted in an HTTPS server. In my case, this server runs on the same computer together with the Telegram bot. That shouldn't be a problem but I mention it just in case.
If I send the url as a message to some user in Telegram, the page can be opened by Telegram on its embedded browser ( or any other for that matter ) perfectly well.

I tested different python bot libraries and different HTTPS servers. The only thing that can be a problem is de SSL certificate. I generate certificates using [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) - Certbot. I have used it for a long time with no troubles at all. The certificates are perfectly legal.

What can be the problem ? I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#testing-web-apps) connect your device to PC/Laptop and debug it from `chrome://inspect/#devices`. Then navigate to the `console` tab and see if any error has occurred.